# node.js remove string from file

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, file-io

I am currently designing a Node.js web server that will store requests as JSON objects and store them in a text file.

An example of said text file is this:

```
{"elements":[
    {"email":"test@test.com","timestamp":"22:10:54"},
    {"email":"foo@foobar.com","timestamp:"09:56:49"}
]}
```

What I want to do is be able to append a given JSON into this text file.  This would be more complicated than a simple fs.append() function, because I have to first get rid of the

```
\n]}
```

that closes the JSON, and then stick on

```
,{"email":"INPUT EMAIL HERE","timestamp":"INPUT TIMESTAMP HERE"}\n]}
```

to form the new completed JSON,

```
{"elements":[
    {"email":"test@test.com","timestamp":"22:10:54"},
    {"email":"foo@foobar.com","timestamp:"09:56:49"},
    {"email":"INPUT EMAIL HERE","timestamp":"INPUT TIMESTAMP HERE"}
]}
```

I want to do all of this without having to load the text file with fs.readFileSync(path), because that would become more difficult with each new entry.  So, my ultimate issue is that I need a way to strip off (effectively reverse-append) a few characters from the end of the file so that I can append on the newly inputted elements.  I've already looked over the doc (http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) and I saw no function for it, but I figured there has to be a way to do it.

Comment: Since you're working with a JSON file in javascript, you could parse it into an actual javascript object, append your new object to the `elements` member, stringify the object, and output it back to a file.

Comment: You see, that was my original idea.  But what if I had a 1,000,000-item long list because of an attack?  I need to be able to do this without actually loading the entire list into RAM.

Comment: Moreover it would be rather slow, where if I can simply append backspaces into the document, it would be very fast.

Comment: leave off the "elements:[" part, and the end close array bracket  and add them back in in the place you call JSON.parse, that way, you can naively append. in short, the file is "almost json". if you need to update instead of insert, you need to parse the whole thing...